# would this cause a retain cycle

Tags: ios, retain-cycle

xCode 5.1, iOS 7.1, ARC
Would this cause a retain cycle on topics? I don't think so, as setting `event=nil` will deallocate the whole tree, so topics will also get deallocated, but I am not sure.

```
 event -> subEvent -> Topics
  |                     ^
  |_____________________|
```

Comment: where is the cycle (loop)?

Comment: This is a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), not a cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to your graphic:

Both 'arrows' go from event to topics. It would be a cycle if the lines/arrows would describe a cycle. (If topics would retain the event.)

The graphic doesn't show a cycle thus there cannot be a retain cycle in there - so no.